# Crystal reports Crosstab date grouping.

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've created a report using the crosstab control which groups the data by date in columns. I'd like to take all of the  dates that are earlier than the 1st of the current month (when the report is run) and combine them and the data being summarized into one column called Previous.

So instead of seeing something like this:

`Oct   Nov   Dec   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul`

I've see something like this:

`Previous   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul`

Is there a way of doing this in CR XI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually a modification of Lee's answer.

```
if {Command.ReqDate} < date(year({?StartDate}),month({?StartDate}),1) then dateadd('m',-1,{?StartDate}) else {Command.ReqDate}

use this to group on in the CT set to monthly
right click on the column header
select Format field,
select common tab
select display string formula
if currentfieldvalue < date(year({?StartDate}),month({?StartDate}),1) then 'previous' 
else totext(currentfieldvalue,'MMM')
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a formula to do this (or probably two formulas one to get them in the correct order and another to display the correct string):

grouping formula: `if {table.datefield} < currentdate then '0000' else cStr({table.datefield}, 'yyMM')`

display formula: `if {table.datefield} < currentdate then 'Previous' else cStr({table.datefield}, 'MMM')`

*ADDED SCREENSHOT*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lee, 

I tried what you suggested, but Crystal always wants to sort on what the column field is. I've tried placing the disp. field in the header and setting the group sort formula (modified for the actual fields/dates in the report) but no luck there.

Comment: i'm not quite sure you understood what i was suggesting. i have added a few screenshots- does that help?

Comment: Lee, That does help. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Lee, I did as you showed in the screen shots, and this is the formula I used in group name formula for the 2nd screen shot.

if {Command.ReqDate} < DateAdd("m", 1, DateTime( Year(CurrentDate))) then 'Previous' else cStr({Command.ReqDate}, 'MMM')

This showed teh date in MMM but I never saw anything under Previous even though there are such records.

Comment: and what did you put in the formula for the group on field?

Comment: if {Command.ReqDate} < DateAdd("m", 1, DateTime( Year(CurrentDate))) then 'Previous' else cStr({Command.ReqDate}, 'MMM')

But this stops the parameter field from working (obviously) I tried it with the {?Start Date} as well also no go. I never saw the "Previous" show up.

Comment: Lee or anyone else? I'm stumped on this. Any suggestions are welcome.